# PHP read decimal integers from xml attributes

Tags: php, simplexml

Using PHP, I would like to write a function that takes numbers from XML, and multiplies those numbers. However, I don't know how to work with decimal numbers in SimpleXML.

PHP

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
'<DOM>
  <TAB id="ID1" width="30.1" height="0.5" ></TAB> 
  <TAB id="ID2" width="15.7" height="1.8" ></TAB>
</DOM>');

foreach ($xml->children() as $second_level) {
    echo $second_level->attributes()->id."<br>";
    echo ($second_level->attributes()->width * 10)."<br>";
    echo ($second_level->attributes()->height * 10)."<br>";
}
```

The current (wrong) output:

```
ID1 
300
0
ID2
150
10
```

The correct output should be:

```
ID1
301
5
ID2
157
18
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are on the right lines, but just to clarify exactly what needs to be cast when, and therefore where parentheses need to go. Unlike other types in PHP, SimpleXML objects are never automatically cast to `float`, so mathematical operators like `*` cast them to `int` instead. (I [filed this is as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53033), but it was closed on the grounds that PHP's internals don't have a way of implementing it.)

You therefore need to cast *the SimpleXML value* to a `float` (AKA `double`) *before* applying any mathematical operations to it. In order to force this in the right order without an intermediate assignment, you would need exactly one set of extra parentheses: `((float)$simplexml_value) * $some_number`.

However, as the [Operator Precedence table in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) shows, type casts such as `(float)` are already higher precedence than `*`, which is higher precedence than `.`, so the below code runs as desired without any extra parentheses ([live demo in multiple PHP versions](http://3v4l.org/0Ik5Y)):

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_level) {
    echo $second_level->attributes()->id . "<br>";
    echo (float)$second_level->attributes()->width * 10 . "<br>";
    echo (float)$second_level->attributes()->height * 10 . "<br>";
}
```

Assigning to an intermediate variable immediately after casting will also work, as the multiplication will prefer to convert the `integer` 10 to a `float` than convert the `float` variable to an `integer` ([live demo](http://3v4l.org/kCVeV)):

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_level) {
    echo $second_level->attributes()->id . "<br>";
    $width = (float)$second_level->attributes()->width;
    echo $width * 10 . "<br>";
    $height = (float)$second_level->attributes()->height;
    echo $height * 10 . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `10` is an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) value, thus the result of that equation will be an integer value too. You have to cast all values to [floats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_level) {
    echo $second_level->attributes()->id."<br>";
    echo (float) ((float) $second_level->attributes()->width * (float) 10)."<br>";
    echo (float) ((float) $second_level->attributes()->height * (float) 10)."<br>";
}
```

EDIT: Ubuntu 13.04 XAMPP with php 5.4.16, this worked:

```
<?php 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
    '<DOM>
          <TAB id="ID1" width="30.1" height="0.5" ></TAB> 
          <TAB id="ID2" width="15.7" height="1.8" ></TAB>
    </DOM>');

foreach ($xml->children() as $second_level) {
    echo $second_level->attributes()->id."<br>";
    echo (float) ((float) $second_level->attributes()->width * 10)."<br>";
    echo (float) ((float) $second_level->attributes()->height * 10)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: thank you, but your code has the same wrong output, as my code... :(

Comment: Try adding an extra `(float)` after `echo`: `echo (float)((float) ... ` I have updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: still the same output :(

Comment: Then perhaps using `floatval($second_level->attributes()->width)`? What happens if you just echo the attribute value without applying anything to it: `echo $second_level->attributes()->width;`

Comment: In the 3rd example you can see that the value is initially a rounded number. Something in `SimpleXMLElement` is screwing this up for you it seems. Last shot: `echo (float) $second_level->attributes()->width;` If that does not give a floating point number I have no idea what you can do.

Comment: I'd say try a newer version of PHP/WAMP (XAMPP even perhaps)

Comment: It's not the `10` that needs casting, but the SimpleXML object, as can easily be seen by the fact that `1.5 * 10` returns `15`, not `10`, as does `'1.5' * 10` which includes an automatic cast from `string` to `float` on the first operand.

Comment: `echo (float) $second_level->attributes()->width;` ? This returned an integer. I also don't see a `1.5` anywhere but in your comment.

Comment: @AmazingDreams `1.5 * 10` was just an example of a `float * int` being interpreted as `float * float` not `int * int`. `echo (float) $second_level->attributes()->width;` works fine in all the configurations checked by this demo: http://3v4l.org/jWFTd (apart from PHP versions below 5.1.2, which cast to `0` on both `(int)` and `(float)`).

Comment: @IMSoP well, if you had properly read the comments, you could have seen that your solution was already proposed, like 4 times.

Comment: @AmazingDreams I was offering a clarification, not a criticism; apologies if the tone did not come across correctly. I only tested the `echo (float)...` line because you mentioned it; nowhere in my first comment am I suggesting any particular solution, just information related to your answer.

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood you, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the values to double by this code:

```
(double) ($second_level->attributes()->width) * 10
```

Comment: thank you, but this code has the same wrong output, as my code... :(

Comment: Strange, because it produces exactly the right output on my computer (301, 157, etc.) I'm using PHP 5.3.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Make sure the (double) is applying only to ($second_level->attributes()->width) before it gets multiplied by the 10. You might have your parentheses in the wrong place.

Comment: I'using WAMP localhost server with php 5.4.3, and I tried this code on my domain - here is the test with wrong output http://ynternet.sk/111.php

Comment: actualy code on my domain is :
      foreach ($xml->children() as $second_level) {
          echo $second_level->attributes()->id."<br>";
          $aaa = (double)($second_level->attributes()->width);
          echo ($aaa * 10)."<br>";
          $bbb = (double)($second_level->attributes()->height);
          echo ($bbb * 10)."<br>";
      }

Comment: Note that `double` is a largely historical synonym for `float`, unlike in other languages where different precisions of floating point numbers may be available. It's even possible that a higher precision could be implemented in a new version of PHP without introducing a new variable type.