# How to take data from XML with PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

Using PHP, I would like to write a function that list all elements + childs and all their attributtes. I want to use DOM, but not SimpleXMLElement.

XML SAMPLE

```
 <DOM>
   <TAB id="ID1" width="30,1" height="0,5" >
     <CHILD aaa="50.12" bbb="50.45" />
     <CHILD aaa="78.06" bbb="6.12" />
   </TAB> 
   <TAB id="ID2" width="15,7" height="1,8" >
     <CHILD aaa="2.60" bbb="5.32" />
   </TAB> 
 </DOM>
```

I need Ouput like this :

```
TAB id:ID1  width:30.1  height:0.5
  CHILD aaa:50.12 bbb:50.45
  CHILD aaa:78.06 bbb:6.12
TAB id:ID2  width:15.7  height:1.8
  CHILD aaa:2.60 bbb:5.32
```

Comment: Could you explain why no simpleXML?

Comment: @Martijn because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035163/php-read-decimal-integers-from-xml-attributes

Comment: If that is the problem, you should fix that problem. You should not try to make a clone of something native just because you can't get integers/floats/doubles properly :) I suggest you try to fix the problem with the calculation, not this way

Comment: Please also read the comments @Martijn. `echo (float) $second_level->attributes()->width` shows an integer value.

Comment: I tried SimpleXML to several servers (about 6 servers) with several versions of PHP. Every time I got the same result. SimpleXML unable Multiply number given by the attribute. It's probably error in SimpleXML, but I can not update PHP verzion on my domain. Current verzion is the 5.4 ... I will not downgrade PHP version on my server, becouse it is also not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Although, you specifically asked NOT to use SimpleXML refering to another question, I have no issues with calculations using the following:

```
<?php

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<DOM>
   <TAB id="ID1" width="30,1" height="0,5" >
     <CHILD aaa="50.12" bbb="50.45" />
     <CHILD aaa="78.06" bbb="6.12" />
   </TAB> 
   <TAB id="ID2" width="15,7" height="1,8" >
     <CHILD aaa="2.60" bbb="5.32" />
   </TAB> 
 </DOM>');


foreach($xml->TAB as $tab)
{
    $attrib = $tab->attributes();
    echo "TAB id:".$attrib['id']."  width:".str_replace(",",".", $attrib['width'])."  height:".str_replace(",",".", $attrib['height'])."\n";

    foreach($tab->CHILD as $child)
    {
        $attrib = $child->attributes();
        echo "  CHILD aaa:".$attrib['aaa']."  bbb:".str_replace(",",".", $attrib['bbb'])."\n";
    }       
}
```

Testing with the following, calculations works like expected:

```
echo (float) str_replace(",",".", $attrib['width']) * (float) str_replace(",",".", $attrib['height']);
```

Comment: I specialy asked NOT to use SimpleXMl, becouse > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035163/php-read-decimal-integers-from-xml-attributes

Comment: I read the question. You can ignore my answer if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not use SimpleXML, bescouse there is a problem with multipling... I tried your code, and there is still that problem.

Comment: I have no issues multiplying. I expect the problem is either local or you are doing something other than what I do.